# Is there a way to access properties from class instances created using in memory code compiled by roslyn in c#

Tags: c#, .net-core, compilation, roslyn

I am trying to create a simple method that will compile some arbitrary class and then give me access to that classes properties using .Net Core 3.0 and the Roslyn compiler.

I have successfully got the code to compile and the instance created however it appears as everything is static and private.

Here is the code:

```
        private void ExecuteOnCompileCommand()
        {

            var code = @"
                          using System;

                          namespace CompileTest
                          {

                              public class Test
                              {
                                   public int y { get; set; }
                                   public int x { get; set; }

                              }
                           }";

            var system =  MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location);

            var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(
                    "_" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D"),
                    syntaxTrees: new SyntaxTree[] { CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(code) },
                    references: new [] {system },
                    options: new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary));

            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var compilationResult = compilation.Emit(ms);

                if (compilationResult.Success)
                {
                    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    _assembly = Assembly.Load(ms.ToArray());
                }
            }

            //create instance of class
            var instance = _assembly.CreateInstance(_assembly.DefinedTypes.First().FullName);

    }
```

Once this compiles and runs I hit a break point at the end of the method and I can see the x, and y, and it says it is of type Test, however I cannot set these variables, or even set another variable to their value.

Comment: In what way do you expect to assign their values? like `instance.x = 42;` ? This is not possible. This is a dynamically generated assembly and can only be manipulated using reflection

Comment: Ok I take it back. If you create it like `dynamic instance = _assembly.CreateInstance(_assembly.DefinedTypes.First().FullName);` you can do this: `instance.x = 42;`

Comment: @OguzOzgul That did the trick. Thank you.

Comment: Can you mark as answer if I put it there? :)

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: If there's something about the class that you expect to be there, I would suggest implementing an interface, or deriving from a base type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in the usual way, but

If you create it like

```
dynamic instance = _assembly.CreateInstance(_assembly.DefinedTypes.First().FullName);
```

you can do this:

```
instance.x = 42;
```

But please remember that we are giving up on strong typing here and any errors will be thrown at run-time.

Thank you, and be safe.